# Dovecot Admin login

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

Does Dovecot allow me to authenticate as an administrator for all user accounts? Essentially log into any account as an administrator.

I'm trying to setup Zimbra and I would like to migrate our IMAP from Dovecot -> Zimbra. In order to do so I would have to have a manager or administrator login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer to my question.

The details for logging as an admin are found here:

http://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/MasterUsers